# Azure Automation Runbook missing mandatory parameters

Tags: azure, automation

I'm trying to set a Tag on all virtual machines in my subscription but I keep getting errors when running the Runbook.
The error is the following:

```
Get-AzureRmVM : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: ResourceGroupName. At line:30
```

Here is my Runbook:

```
    $azureConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

#Authenticate
try {
    Clear-Variable -Name params -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
    $params = @{
        ServicePrincipal = $true
        Tenant = $azureConnection.TenantID
        ApplicationId = $azureConnection.ApplicationID
        CertificateThumbprint = $azureConnection.CertificateThumbprint
    }
    $null = Add-AzureRmAccount @params
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = $_
    Throw "Unable to authenticate with error: $errorMessage"
}

#  Discovery of all Azure VM's in the current subscription.

$azurevms = Get-AzureRmVM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
Write-Host "Discovering Azure VM's in the following subscription $SubscriptionID  Please hold...."

Write-Host "The following VM's have been discovered in subscription $SubscriptionID"
$azurevms

foreach ($azurevm in $azurevms) {

    Write-Host "Checking for tag $vmtagname on $azurevm"
    $tagRGname = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $azurevm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName

    $tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $tagRGname -Name $azurevm).Tags

If ($tags.UpdateWindow){
Write-Host "$azurevm already has the tag $vmtagname."
}
else
{
Write-Host "Creating Tag $vmtagname and Value $tagvalue for $azurevm"
$tags.Add($vmtagname,$tagvalue)

    Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $tagRGname -ResourceName $azurevm -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -Tag $tags -Force `
   }

}

Write-Host "All tagging is done"
```

I tried importing the right modules but this doesn't seem to affect the outcome.
Running the same commands in Cloud Shell does work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the error was caused by this part `Get-AzureRmVM -Name $azurevm`, when running this command, the `-ResourceGroupName` is needed.

[image]

You need to use the `Az` command `Get-AzVM -Name $azurevm`, it will work.

[image]

> Running the same commands in Cloud Shell does work correctly.

In Cloud shell, azure essentially uses the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.1.0) module to run your command, you can understand it runs the `Enable-AzureRmAlias` before the command, you could check that via debug mode.

```
Get-AzureRmVM -Name joyWindowsVM -debug
```

[image]

---

To solve your issue completely, I recommend you to use the new `Az` module, because the `AzureRM` module was deprecated and will not be updated.

Please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to your automation account in the portal -> `Modules`, check if you have imported the modules `Az.Accounts`, `Az.Compute`, `Az.Resources`, if not, go to `Browse Gallery` -> search and import them.

2.After import successfully, change your script to the one like below, then it should work fine.

```
$azureConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

#Authenticate
try {
    Clear-Variable -Name params -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
    $params = @{
        ServicePrincipal = $true
        Tenant = $azureConnection.TenantID
        ApplicationId = $azureConnection.ApplicationID
        CertificateThumbprint = $azureConnection.CertificateThumbprint
    }
    $null = Connect-AzAccount @params
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = $_
    Throw "Unable to authenticate with error: $errorMessage"
}

#  Discovery of all Azure VM's in the current subscription.

$azurevms = Get-AzVM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
Write-Host "Discovering Azure VM's in the following subscription $SubscriptionID  Please hold...."

Write-Host "The following VM's have been discovered in subscription $SubscriptionID"
$azurevms

foreach ($azurevm in $azurevms) {

    Write-Host "Checking for tag $vmtagname on $azurevm"
    $tagRGname = Get-AzVM -Name $azurevm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName

    $tags = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $tagRGname -Name $azurevm).Tags

If ($tags.UpdateWindow){
Write-Host "$azurevm already has the tag $vmtagname."
}
else
{
Write-Host "Creating Tag $vmtagname and Value $tagvalue for $azurevm"
$tags.Add($vmtagname,$tagvalue)

    Set-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $tagRGname -ResourceName $azurevm -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -Tag $tags -Force `
   }

}

Write-Host "All tagging is done"
```